# Node module-like way to build Java programs WITHOUT compiling?

Tags: java, java-8

I'm trying to create a modular structure in Java where:

1. Each "module" is pluggable in a loosely coupled manner
2. No need to compile
3. Each "module" has the same method signature

In node.js I would just do `module.exports` and require it from another file to use, but in Java it looks like there's no way to run a snippet of code without compiling.

Ideally I would like to create a system where these modules are plug and playable just like how I can just put a file in a directory in node.js and require and use immediately without any trouble. The Java files cannot be compiled class files either because I want the source to be visible.

Is there such a way?

Comment: Is OSGi an option?

Comment: Java is not node, Java needs to be compiled. Don't try to shoehorn Java into something it is not. You may even get it to work (I have seen jshell scripts), but it won't be ideal and it will probably hurt.

Comment: You could compile the file prior prior to loading it.

Answer (score 1):

When you say

> how I can just put a file in a directory in node.js and require and use immediately without any trouble. The Java files cannot be compiled class files either because I want the source to be visible

It is not completely clear as to what is your objective. After compiling the code (maybe into a jar), if you want the source code to be visible to the programmer, then use an IDE like IntelliJ which will decompile the classes on the fly and you can navigate the source code without any additional decompilation step.

Coming to the main question, as @Mark Rotteveel said, `Don't try to shoehorn Java into something it is not`. Compilation gives Java its `Platform-Independence`.

You can see the reasoning and advantages behind Java compilation here
[How Java Works](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~jcarroll/15-100-s05/supps/basics/history.html)

Comment: You could even put the sources into the jar tile. Much better than to decompile the class files.

Answer (score 1):

Everyone else has said it, but this... likely isn't the best idea. You may be trying to shoehorn a language you already know into a new language without consideration about what that new language can and can't actually do.

*Having said that*, sure, there's a couple of ways to do what you want:

1. Write [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) instead of Java for some or all of your work. Groovy is 99% compatible with Java: for the most part you can rename your .java files .groovy and they should be syntactically vaild. In Groovy you should be able to dynamically load files and execute them.

   You could also, in a main Java program, execute Groovy. So write your main program in Java then call special Groovy Development Kit classes that compile your class here. In fact Jenkins uses Groovy as a scripting language for almost this exact thing!
2. Write your main program in Java but use the Java [ScriptEngineManager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/index.html) to call other code in other languages. In fact, playing on this concept would allow you to call your Java classes from actual *Javascript*. This might be super useful, depending on what you want to do. Just requires the main program to be compiled Java.
3. Do item #1 except pick a language that's not so compatible with Java syntax. I suspect [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/) might have some features to dynamically load files.
4. You may actually be trying to build a plugin architecture in Java. I suspect there's at least some blog entries on this topic. This would probably require compilation of the plugins, but if you do it right the main program wouldn't have any dependencies on particular plugins. Again, this may be an option depending on where you're going (trying to build your own Minecraft or Photoshop??)

Answer (score 0):

Many good options (and caveats) are already listed in the other answers.

Yet another option: Write a clever Java main, that picks up the source files, transparently compiles them (behind the back of the users if you like :) ) and loads the result into the current JVM. The official way for this would go through [JSR 199](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=199).

The Eclipse debugger is a good example for such on-the-fly compilation and execution. A user selects a code snippet and inspects the value to which it evaluates. Nobody notices that the snippet is being compiled under the hood (unless you have compile errors, i.e.). JSP follow a similar path etc.